# Is there an RFC or equivalent specification for GNU CLI utility help page (--help) format?

Tags: linux, gnu, command-line-interface

I'm writing some *nix CLI utilities and I'd like to standardize my "--help" output for the various scripts, but I'm not sure what standards I should conform to.

I have only found this [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#g_t_002d_002dhelp) standards reference but it doesn't provide any information on best practices / preferred format.  Is there such a thing?

Is there any official spec or at least some pseudo-standards documentation I should try to adhere to?

I know this isn't a direct programming question, so let me know if there's another StackExchange it's better suited for.

Thanks!

Comment: GNU is standards for GNU.

Comment: I am pretty sure no because it's never intended to be machine parsed but perhaps that's not a requirement of RFCs and just my experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, not RFC but still a pretty good example of the conventional help output fromat could be found on [docopt.org](http://docopt.org/) Even if you aren't going to use that DSL to implement your CLI interface, you really should read its documentation to get general ideas of 'standard' help.

Also you can find some useful information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Built-in_usage_help) and on [opengroup.org](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)